# Problems with docker container to container communication on same host when firewalld/iptables is enabled

Tags: networking, docker

Here is my configuration :

- Host Virtual Machine is CentOS 7.1
- Docker version is 1.8.1
- Container    1 -> exposes port 8071 and runs a web service
- Container 2 -> exposes    port 8081 and runs a front end web app
- firewalld is enabled and    running

Following works - (let's say the IP address of host centos VM is 10.7.42.182)

- when accessed from browser on client machine http://10.7.42.182:8071/ does connect to the web service in container 1
- when accessed from browser on client machine http://10.7.42.182:8081/ does connect to the web app in container 2
- When I do ping 10.7.42.182 from inside container 2
- IP address of container 1 is 172.17.0.1. When I do ping to 172.17.0.1 from insider container 2
- When I access http://172.17.0.1:8071/ from inside container 2

Following does not work -

- When I access http://10.7.42.182:8071/ from inside container 2

## #

http://10.7.42.182:8071 can be accessed from my clients however not from with in another container running on the same host !!

When I turn off firewalld then it starts to work.

How is firewalld creating a problem here ? i.e. allows connection from outside but not from with in the container ?

Would appreciate any hints on what may be happening.